# ¿Cómo restar 2 columnas de fecha y mostrar en resultado en horas?

Tags: python, pandas

Mi duda es como restar dos columnas pertenecientes a un `dataframe` y el resultado mostrarlo en horas (con los decimales incluidos).

Las dos columnas de fechas están transformadas a `datetime`:

```
fecha1 2018-09-11 11:31:09
fecha2 2018-09-10 10:30:38
resultado 25.008611  horas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tus columnas son de tipo `numpy.datetime64` como debería ser dado que el tipo nativo que usa Pandas (habría que ver como parseas esas columnas de no ser así), puedes restarlas directamente, con lo que obtienes una columna (`Serie`) con la diferencia con tipo  `TimeDelta.` Para pasarlo a horas basta con dividir entre el `Timedelta` que representa una hora:

```
import pandas as pd



data = {
        "a": ("2018-09-11 11:31:09", "2018-09-14 13:25:14"),
        "b": ("2018-09-10 10:30:38", "2018-09-14 11:05:38")
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype="datetime64[ns]")
df["c"] = (df.a - df.b) / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
```

---

> ```
> >>> df
>                     a                   b          c
> 0 2018-09-11 11:31:09 2018-09-10 10:30:38  25.008611
> 1 2018-09-14 13:25:14 2018-09-14 11:05:38   2.326667
> ```

Comment: muchas gracias! era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 3):

Este código de puede servir u orientar para lo que quieres. La precisión de los decimales está dada en segundos.

```
import datetime

def restar_fechas(fecha1, fecha2):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    diff = end_date - start_date
    return diff.days*24 + diff.seconds/3600

# valores de prueba
print(restar_fechas('2018-09-10 10:30:38', '2018-09-10 11:31:09'))
print(restar_fechas('2018-09-10 10:30:38', '2018-09-11 11:31:09'))
```

Salida

```
1.0086111111111111
25.00861111111111
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero en mi caso fecha1 y fecha2 son dos columnas de un dataframe
df['fecha1'] y df['fecha2']
al implementar lo que tu me dices me da este error: